# Need a folder to be routed making all the contains inside that folder available

Tags: angularjs, routes

Hi guys i need to actually route a folder which will be containing multiple files and folder inside it.

```
For example 
My folder name is Contains -- with inner folder  sample1 sample2.
sample1 folder contains --  app.js index.js Index.html 
sample2 folder contains --  app.js index.js Index.html

so I want routes for like every file in each folder's 
example --  localhost:3030/Contains/sample1/Index.html
localhost:3030/Contains/sample2/Index.html
localhost:3030/Contains/sample1/index.js
localhost:3030/Contains/sample1/app.js
... etc
```

How can I achieve this using stateProvider?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do u want routes for js files ? 
For HTML you can provide path directly in `templateURL`

Comment: I actually have a Scorm course folder and I want all the contents related to that cause to be loaded. so need to route  each and every file in that folder .

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question here I am using triple level nesting

```
var app = angular.module("Appp", ['ui.router']);
    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('userSetting', {
                url: '/userSetting',
                templateUrl: 'templates/userSetting.html'
            })
            .state('settings.profile.user', {
                url: '/profile',
                templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProController'
            })
            .state('settings.account.user', {
                url: '/account',
                templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
                controller: 'AccController'
            });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/userSetting/profile');
    });
```

Comment: triple level nesting is fine but in that case, I will have to declare multiple routes. and the  cause folder  will actually  contain like more than 40 files